# Trigger backgroundFetch with UILocalnotification?

Tags: ios, background, notifications

PeopleInTheKnow!

I'm writing this app, that uses Background Fetch, to see if there's some new information on a server. 
Background Fetch works fine, but is pretty unpredictable in when it performs its trick.
Therefore, I though I should use scheduled UILocalNotifications, so I have more control over the exact timing and frequency of the execution of the method associated with Background Fetch.

But this is where I get confused:

My scheduled UILocalNotifications fire as expected. But **the delegate**

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{
    // I recieved a notification
    NSString * notificationType = [notification.userInfo valueForKey:@"dailyCheck"];
    NSLog(@"Received Notification of type %@",notificationType);
}
```

in which I would like to call the server check method, **is only called when the app is active**. 
This seems to make such a mechanism useless for my case.
Could any of you advise me what would be the best approach, to make sure that my app, be it in the foreground or background, will check the server every day at a a specific time?

I should add, that I don't expect any user interaction here. So, no alerts with buttons or anything like it.

Thanks ahead

Comment: The only way you can get your app to check at a specific time is to send a silent push from a server at the specific time.

Comment: How disappointing. Thanks.